# core-list must either be sized or be inside an overflow:auto div that is sized

Tags: dom, polymer, web-component

I'm using the Polymer core-list in a page and the display provides a good result, but when I try to use this file as a Polymer custom element, it shows me this error :   **core-list must either be sized or be inside an overflow:auto div that is sized.**

How to resolve this problem please ?

Comment: Can you show some code how you use `core-list-dart`? Is this about Polymer.js or Polymer.dart?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer This problem is related to this post too :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29735745/polymer-uncaught-error-template-must-be-cleared-before-a-new-bindingdelegate-c?noredirect=1#comment47620582_29735745

Check the code in the comments. Thank you for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Because your question doesn't provide much information just a guess. You are missing

```dart
<polymer-element name="xxx">
  <style>
    :host {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
  <core-list-dart>
  ...
</polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [core-list documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/elements/core-list.html):

> IMPORTANT: core-list must ether be explicitly sized, or delegate
>   scrolling to an explicitly sized parent. By "explicitly sized", we
>   mean it either has an explicit CSS height property set via a class or
>   inline style, or else is sized by other layout means (e.g. flex or
>   fit). Alternatively, core-list can delegate scrolling to a scrollable
>   element that contains the list by setting the scrollTarget property,
>   and the same explicit sizing requiremets will apply to that element.

You should be good to go, if you set a height property for your element.

```
<polymer-element name="somename">
  <style>
    :host {
      display: block;
    }
    .someclass {
      height:10vh;
    }
  </style>
  <core-list-something class="someclass">
  ...
</polymer-element>
```